# how should we think about using of "being" and "comma"

Tags: meaning

There are two sentences.

> (1) The lateral fourth tarsalbone is constantly present and, **being much deeper than the others,** intrudes into the middle tier.

- First of all, is "being" gerund or present participle in this sentence ?
- Can we think "being much deeper than others" as "***which are*** being much deeper than others"
  **Which refers to "The lateral fourth tarsalbone"**

> (2) The palpebral skin is thin and **, being loosely *attached,*** is thrown into folds when the eye is open.

- The second one has a past participle. Likewise, can we say as **"which are being loosely attached"**

And "commas"

Comment: *Which are being X" turns the sentence into a passive construction, and is not the same as "being X". I think this is likely to be better explained on ELL.

Answer (score 0):

This is a tricky language question. English differs from many other languages in its usage of the verb ‘to be’.

First, in your sentence, ‘being’ is a participle. But you cannot say “... because it is being ...” in this context: you should just say “... because it is ...”. [There is a special usage of the word ‘being’ to refer to someone’s behaviour or intentions. So “You are being difficult/foolish/wise/funny...”]

“It is being attached” is a continuous present. It means the same as “(someone) is attaching it”. So the correct English for what you want to say is: “... it is attached...”. There is more to say

I shall have a look.  Most grammars will have something.  The main point is this.  Most languages I know (other than English) have only one form of present tense, where English has two:
1) “I work in Paris.”
2) “I am working in Paris.
1) tells you the location of my job.  So I could say this in August, when on holiday on the Côté Bleu.  2) tells you what I am doing now (as I speak).  It is often called a ‘continuous present’.  In French, 1 & 2 would both be expressed as « Je travaille à Paris ».  To make it clear that you mean 1), you would have to say something like « Je suis en train de travailler à Paris ».

But the verb *to be* cannot work like that.  I cannot be something without being it now.

EXCEPT  that special usage of ‘being’ which almost the same as ‘behaving’:  so “you are being foolish” is the same as “you are behaving foolishly”.

I shall look for a reference, but I hope this helps for now.